# VirtualBox - Make VMs talk only to each other and Internet

Tags: virtualbox

Using VirtualBox, how can I set it up so that my two VMs see each other on their own network, and have access to the internet, but do not see other physical boxes on the host's network?

I'm trying to do MITM testing with Kali Linux and another VM (Lubuntu) and I don't want Kali to "attack" any other boxes on the real network my host is attached to, only the Lubuntu VM.

I know I can set up NatNetwork. I got that working. But then the Kali VM can see other boxes on the network, and potentially cause damage. I tried Host-Only, and Kali could see Lubuntu on the network, but neither could access the internet.

Comment: Think about what you're asking.  If these were physical machines, how would you achieve this?  If the machines are all connected to the same swtich (Bridged Networking acts like a switch, NAT acts like a switch with a NAT router between the switch and the VMs), how would you get this kind of separation?

Comment: How much Internet access do they need? Would it be acceptable to limit them to web access through a proxy server?

Comment: @Kenster I think so. I saw basically two options but I couldn't seem to get them working: Either use Windows Internet Connection Sharing to give the Virtual Network internet access, or, since the guest VMs should be able to talk to the host in host-only mode, make the host their internet proxy.